# how to check is something like this isn't already made by someone else

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to implement a excel like interface, but as a webapp. It is not really excel like, but this is the must appropriate term to describe it.

Basically it is about a form with 20 cells(1 row with 20 inputs) and the working scenario is this: when the user clicks on a cell, that input box becomes a textarea and the user enters the desired text in it. On the bottom right side of the text area I need a button which save the textarea content through ajax.

Do you have any idea, if this type of functionality is offered (even partially), by any of the jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out something like:

http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/uiTableEdit

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

There are more too, just google jQuery editable or edit in place, quite a few options.

Answer (score 1):

Most people generally use google for this.
How about http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet.